# Linking button to specific cell in sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to program a button in google sheets to put the current date in time in a predetermined cell but when I try to define the cell (B13) in the script it says "Cannot find method getActiveRange(string)". I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

```
    function setNow1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange('B13').setValue(new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I came up with

```
function spotCar(cellName) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(new Date());
}
function spotCarB13(){
  spotCar("B13", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   function setNow1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange('B13').setValue(new Date());
}
```